# shell script for connect server through ssh terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, ssh, scripts, gnome-terminal

How to write shell script for connect multiple server through ssh terminal.
Its should open  multiple tab in terminal and connect multiple servers through ssh

ex

```
ssh test@192.168.2.1
ssh test@192.168.2.3
ssh test@192.168.2.5
```

Automatically fill password also

All in separate tab.

how to write shell script for this ?

Comment: The only safe way to use `ssh` without password is using public key authentication. See for example a tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2 . After that @p-h-lin answer fits the bill.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `gnome-terminal` to open up new terminal or new tabs

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# The following command open new windows
#
gnome-terminal -e "ssh test@192.168.2.1"
gnome-terminal -e "ssh test@192.168.2.3"
gnome-terminal -e "ssh test@192.168.2.5"
#
# The following command open new tabs
#
gnome-terminal --tab -e "ssh test@192.168.2.1" --tab -e "ssh test@192.168.2.3"
```

Another solution will be using the `screen` command, an example of this when it's written in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create a detached screen name with "node1"
screen -d -m -S node1
# Create a detached screen name with "node3"
screen -d -m -S node3
# Start another screen within node1
screen -S node1 -X screen
# Execute your command in the screen instance of node1
screen -S node1 -p 0 -X exec ssh test@192.168.2.1
# Same as above
screen -S node3 -X screen
screen -S node3 -p 0 -X exec ssh test@192.168.2.3
```

After finished running this script, you could open the screen instance that you just created with `screen -r node1`, for more about the `screen` command please refer to [Screen User's Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).

Reference:

1. [shell script - open a new tab in terminal](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=509123)
2. [bash script to open 1 screen session with multiple windows?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1540595)

Comment: Multiple tab not supporting

Comment: It works for me, Ubuntu 12.04.5 with GNOME Terminal 3.4.1.1

Comment: Sorry i'm using 14.04

Comment: Sorry it work on 14.04.1 as well, GNOME Terminal 3.6.2, this is my command for testing: `gnome-terminal --tab -e "mtr google.com" --tab -e "mtr ubuntu.com"
`

Comment: its working gnome-terminal --tab -e "ssh test@192.168.2.1" --tab -e "ssh test@192.168.2.1" Thanks #P.-H but i want with password

Comment: @VtrKanna You added the requirement for password after the answer was posted. If this answer works, I suggest you accept it, and research or ask a new question about automatic passwords.